# Typescript remap Array Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is it possible to remap type of array (or maybe tuple?)

Let's say that I have an array of functions and I want to make of it array of functions captured parameters. Something like.

```
type Remap<F extends ((... args: any) => any)[]> =
    F extends [infer T1] ? [Parameters<T1>] :
    F extends [infer T1, infer T2] ? [Parameters<T1>, Parameters<T2>] :
    F extends [infer T1, infer T2, infer T3] ? [Parameters<T1>, Parameters<T2>,  Parameters<T3>] :
    never;

const a = [(a: string) => void, (b: number) => void]
type T = Remap<typeof a> // [[string], [number]] - simply captured arguments of functions.
```

What i need to is pass array of functions like "a" and create maybe new function which will contain parameters from all functions like ([first arguments], [second arguments]).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mapped type to map a tuple:

```
type Remap<F extends ((...args: any) => any)[]> = {
  [P in keyof F]: F[P] extends (...a: infer P) => any ? P: never
}

declare const a: [(a: string) => void, (b: number) => void]
type T = Remap<typeof a>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAShC2BDMAeAYlCAPYEB2AJgM5QAUpAdFYgE4DmRAXFIniAJRQC8AfC2+wDaAXT5coAbwBQUKIIAKUAJZ4oAawggA9gDMoaYczQLhmHPmJkqFRMxU6INKPM69+IKAH5nzPBABujlIAvlJSBBAAxgA2tNCRWnhEwCzMgqS2UMk0KnSufP5aSgQANGQARr4ArvDljvlQhcXCUqCQUAAq3LAIyChtELosPEA)

Comment: @luky wops, initially repasted the same code..hope you saw the updated mapped tuple version (it was always in the playground link..)

Comment: yes i saw it there, but first i was looking for the changes :)

Comment: and (...params: T) is [[string], [number]] and if i wanted [string, number]?